# How to rename or drop specific DataFrame column if there are other columns with same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can one rename a specific column in a pandas DataFrame when the colum name is not unique?
Calling `df.rename(columns={'old_name':'new_name'}` will rename all the columns with the name "old_name".
Same question for dropping a column when there are duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since calling `df.rename(columns={'old_name':'new_name'}` will rename all the columns called "old_name", renaming must be done with the column index.

Get all the indexes of the column of interest:
`[col_index for col_index, col_name in enumerate(df.columns) if col_name in col_name_to_find]`

**Rename:**
Once you know which index you'd like to rename: `df.columns.values[col_index] = new_col_name`

**Dropping:**
One option is to use pandas built-in [duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method, giving you the option to keep only the first or last column, or remove them all.
`df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated(keep="first")]`.
This is helpful only if you want to drop all, the first or last duplicate column.

If you have more than 2 duplicated columns and want to keep one that is not the first or last, you can:

1. Get all the indexes of the column of interest (as explained above) as a list.
2. Remove the index you want to keep in the df from the list.
3. calling `df.drop(df.iloc[:,[list_of_column_indexes_to_drop]], axis=1)`